# Is there a built-in way to remap illegal characters in Samba when sharing with Windows?

Tags: windows, share, samba, remap, illegal-characters

I have a samba share set up in ubuntu. Many of the folders and filenames contain : which is an illegal character in Windows. Samba's default action when dealing with illegal characters is to mangle the file/folder name to the old DOS/Win3.1 8.3 format (8 chars, period, 3 char extension).

I've looked around and found that you can turn mangling off, but then the illegally-named folder is inaccessible.  I also found a parameter called 'mangled map' which lets you remap the names, but it seems to no longer be valid and is only usable if you also use the 8.3 mangling.

Is there a way to remap the illegal char : to something else (like _ or -) in the share?

Comment: Just a thought experiment: How would you access a folder that *actually* contains `-` in place of the `:` when both exist in the same location, then?

Comment: A workaround is to make Windows compatible symlinks on the server